# jquery ajax form submit with twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i'm developing a chat and i want that the clients click on the button **"Click here and start ur chat"** and will open the form and after submit form **"Start Chat"**...

But i can't submit using ajax, i checked the console log, nothing appears strange!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Start Chat</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/chat.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <center> 

            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Click here and start ur chat
    </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Write ur info below</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="" method="POST" id="form">                    
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>                        
                            <td>Name: </td> <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        <tr>                        
                            <td>Mail: </td> <td><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Mail"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start Chat</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
            <!-- javascript:chatWith('3','Ronaldo') -->

    </center>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){   

            $("#start").click(function(){
                $("#form").submit(function(e){

                    $.ajax({

                        url: "dateRecd.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: $(this).serialize(),

                        success: function(data){
                            alert(data);
                        //  chatWith('9','name');
                        }


                    });

                });
            });     
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You for sure need to preventDefault if you Ajax the form. Also Now you just assign the submit handler. It is not executed

Comment: did your schema like this : start(click) => show modal => click submit chat; ?

Comment: I'm not sure about preventDefault, can i remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead submit in the form, kindly try with the "click" action.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

        $("#form").click(function(e){

            $.ajax({

                url: "dateRecd.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),

                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                //  chatWith('9','name');
                }


            });

        });
    //});     
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, what happens when you click the button "start" ? As you add a click handler to the "start" button, as following :

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
//...
}
```

you **add** a sumbit handler of the form when you click the button. nothing more, no submit, no ajax action.

To get what you want, there are 2 simple ways:

1. in the click handler of the button, delete the form submit handler,
   and do the ajax submit, like what @Thiru says;
2. delete the button click handler, use form submit handler, like @Faytraneozter propoese.

But the second way doesn't work. why?

Firstly, you have 4 buttons in your page, how does your page know which button clicked should fire the submit action? You should add 
    `type="submit"`
to the button, so that your page knows that when you click this button, you mean to submit the form.

Secondly, when you fire the submit action of the form, it is submitted by HTML, **NOT** ajax. You should add the line `e.preventDefault` to prevent the submit by HTML. Here is https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1165178 a answer which explains well `e.preventDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the **#start** click

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   

        //$("#start").click(function(){ // that will done a double verification
            $("#form").submit(function(e){

                $.ajax({

                    url: "dateRecd.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),

                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    //  chatWith('9','name');
                    }


                });

            });
        //});     
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Change this

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start Chat</button>

To this

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start Chat</button>

An put it INSIDE the <form> tag

Comment: shouldn't you put async:false?